# Why is python handling JSON giving me this error?

Tags: python, json, matplotlib

So what the code is trying to do is pull data from this URL, which is a JSON object. The data I'm getting from the URL is the `x-cen` and `y-cen` coordinates. I put the `coords` in their respective lists for later plotting. Everything works out fine with getting the information. However, it gives me the following error:

> "TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''".

How do I fix this?

```
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    import json
    import matplotlib.cm as cm
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.patches import Circle, PathPatch
    from matplotlib.path import Path
    from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D
    import numpy as np
    import pylab
    import re

    dates = []
    xcen = []
    ycen = []
    sciObj = []
    def getNumberOfEntries(theJSON):
        return len(dates)   

    def getInfo(counter, theJSON):
        cont = True
        while cont:
    try:
        dates.append(theJSON["Events"][counter]["date"])
        xcen.append(theJSON["Events"][counter]["xCen"])
        ycen.append(theJSON["Events"][counter]["yCen"])
        sciObj.append(theJSON["Events"][counter]["sciObjectives"])
        counter = counter + 1
        getInfo(counter, theJSON)
    except IndexError:
        cont = False
    break

    def setXMax(theJSON):      
        xmax = xcen[0]
        for i in range (1, getNumberOfEntries(theJSON)-1):
            if xcen[i] > xmax:
        xmax = xcen[i]
        return int(xmax+10)

    def setXMin(theJSON):
        xmin = xcen[0]
        for i in range (1, getNumberOfEntries(theJSON)-1):
            if xcen[i] < xmin:
        xmin = xcen[i]
        return int(xmin-10)

    def setYMax(theJSON):      
        ymax = ycen[0]
        for i in range (1, getNumberOfEntries(theJSON)-1):
            if ycen[i] > ymax:
                ymax = ycen[i]
        return int(ymax+10)

    def setYMin(theJSON):
        ymin = ycen[0]
        for i in range (1, getNumberOfEntries(theJSON)-1):
            if ycen[i] < ymin:
                ymin = ycen[i]
        return int(ymin-10)         

    def plot():

        print('It got to here')

        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(25, 15))
        circle = Circle((0, 0), 980, facecolor='none', edgecolor=(0, 0.8, 0.8), linewidth=3, alpha=0.5)
ax.add_patch(circle)

plt.plot(xcen, ycen, 'ro', color = 'blue')
plt.plot(xcen, ycen, color = 'red')

pylab.xlim([setXMin, setXMax])
pylab.ylim([setYMin, setYMax])

for xy in zip(xcen, ycen):
    ax.annotate('(%s, %s)' % xy, xy=xy, textcoords='data') 

ax.set_xticks(np.arange(setXMin, setXMax))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(setYMin, setYMax))

plt.grid()
plt.show()

    def main():
        urlData = "http://www.lmsal.com/hek/hcr?cmd=search-events3&outputformat=json&instrument=IRIS&noaanum=11856&hasData=true"
        webUrl = urlopen(urlData)
        counter = 0
        if (webUrl.getcode()==200):                
            data = webUrl.read().decode('utf-8')
            theJSON = json.loads(data)
            getInfo(counter, theJSON)
        else:
            print ("You done messed up!!!")

        for i in range (0, getNumberOfEntries(theJSON)):
            print(dates[i])
            print("(", xcen[i], ", ", ycen[i], ")")
            print(sciObj[i])
            print(' ')

    main()
    plot()
```

Comment: Update your question to include the full error traceback.  We need to see the code that _caused_ the error, not just the error message.

Comment: @AndrewQuoc-AnhHo your indentation looks *very* odd. Please make sure the code above corresponds to your actual code. And: check the types of the things you obtain from JSON. Something you're trying to plot or use otherwise is not the type the given function expects. And probably not what you expect it to be.